# How to handle API keys in code when using git and deployment platforms like Heroku?

Tags: git, api, heroku

I want to run a Discord bot of mine on Heroku, however i am scared that through missunderstanding how it works i will accidently make my API keys publicly visible. Is there a best practice solution that i could follow here?

This is what i would try:

- Clone the git repo (the code there obviously having the API keys removed)
- Manually add the keys without commiting the changes
- Pushing the code with the keys to the heroku remote master

However i am not 100% sure if pushing the code with the keys to a remote master will be something that others could see, so i would rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: You can't push uncommitted code to a remote, so you'd have to make and then undo the commit. Instead you should [store config in the environment](https://12factor.net/config) and read if from there.

Comment: so instead of creating a .env and commiting it without the keys, i should just not commit it at all and manually add it to the environment? thanks, ill have to check how to actually do that in Heroku but it sounds good

Comment: That's covered in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars - you can still have a `.env` to set those things in your dev environment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bheroku%5D+password, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bheroku%5D+secrets